# Can I find my Google Assistant reminders, shop list and remembered info somewhere outside my phone

Tags: google-assistant

If I want to add a reminder or change my shopping list I can do it only using Google Assistant on my phone. But it's not always usable.

**Can I work with Google Assistant or simply edit such info using a PC?**

I tried to install Google Allo but it seems like it uses some different information that isn't shared with my phone (even tho I logged in with the same Google account).

Comment: Note: Google will stop supporting Allo in March 2019